# Responsive table-like design

Tags: html, html-table, responsive-design

In a form four properties have to be set by the user. I chose a table like layout:

[image]

This layout, however, makes problems on smaller screens. In this case, I would like to have:

[image]

and on very small screens:

[image]

Any idea? I am using HTML5, CSS3, jQuery 3.3.1 and bootstrap 2.

Comment: Check out `flexbox` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: you can just make use of grid system in bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you intend use **table** to make your form stay in a good layout.
it's **not** recommended this way because you can't rearrange the cell in a table freely. Or should I say, don't use **table** to make a **responsive layout**.

Bootstrap grid system is responsive by default so you should make use of it.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

In your case, you can put your element in four div tag like this

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <!-- your first element -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <!-- your second element -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <!-- your third element -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <!-- your fourth element -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with flexbox:

Here my CSS:

```
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: center;
    }

        .flex-container > div {
            margin: 1px;
        }

        .flex-container > .label {
            padding-left: 8px;
            width: 20%;
            min-width: 100px;
        }

        .flex-container > .value {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

    .line-break {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .cond-line-break {
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
        .cond-line-break {
            display: inline;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
        .cond-line-break {
            display: inline;
        }

        .flex-container > .label {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="label">Property 1:</div>
    <div class="value">
        <select>
            <option selected="selected">Value 1</option>
            <option>Value 2</option>
            <option>Value 3</option>
            <option>Value 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cond-line-break"></div>
    <div class="label">Enter Property 2 here:</div>
    <div class="value">
        <select>
            <option>Value 1</option>
            <option selected="selected">Value 2</option>
            <option>Value 3</option>
            <option>Value 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="line-break"></div>
    <div class="label">Property 3:</div>
    <div class="value">
        <select>
            <option>Value 1</option>
            <option>Value 2</option>
            <option selected="selected">Value 3</option>
            <option>Value 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cond-line-break"></div>
    <div class="label">Property 4:</div>
    <div class="value">
        <select>
            <option>Value 1</option>
            <option>Value 2</option>
            <option>Value 3</option>
            <option selected="selected">Value 4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works as intended, even with labels of different length.